# Sharepoint 2010 List View trouble: doesn't work CAML query for group selection

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010, caml, usergroups

I've created a "By my group" view in Schema.xml for a TaskList, using best known solution:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
     <Or>
      <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
        <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
      </Membership>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
        <Value Type="Integer">
          <UserID/>
        </Value>
      </Eq>
    </Or>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

However, It doesn't work for me...
Possible reason: I'm using FBA authentication with tokens (I've noticed, that after login

```
SPFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(securityToken);
```

User disappeared from SharePoint group).
But!
I checked next query:

```
string camlquery = 
"<Where>
      <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" />
          <Value Type=\"Text\">" + SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups[0].Name+ "</Value>
      </Eq>
</Where>";
```

And it worked!

The problem is that i can't insert

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups[0].Name
```

into the Schema.xml markup

Any ideas about presenting TaskList View for corresponding UserGroup ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, My fault. The problem was in custom Membership Provider. It was a little bit mixed up (Authentication in Membership used CardId as a login, and in SharePoint login was like a Name+Surname).
That's why `<Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">` had no UserGroups, cause it was corresponding user with Login 'CardId' while in SharePoint groups where assigned to users with login Name+Surname.

First Question on stackoverflow failed ^_^.